# Parse a WAV file and export PCM data

Tags: beginner, c, audio, file-structure

I'm a newbie and I wrote code that gets a WAV file and exports a RAW (only PCM data) to *.raw file. But I am confused about the structure. The code is written as one procedure (LISP style) and there are no functions. Can I get some advice how to reorganize the code?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include "wave.h"

byte buf[5]; // 4 char string buffer
char filename[200]; //
FILE *fp;
FILE *pcm_data;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    strcat(filename, argv[1]);
    struct riff_chunk riff = {"RIFF", 0, "WAVE"};
    struct fmt_chunk fmt = {"fmt "};
    struct data_chunk data = {"data"};

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb"))==NULL) {
        printf("Can't open the file. Exit.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Reading RIFF section
    if (fread(&riff.id, sizeof(byte), 12, fp)!= 12)  {
        printf("Can't read RIFF chunk or EOF is met. Exit.\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        memccpy(buf, riff.id, '\0', 4);
        if (strcmp(buf, "RIFF")!=0) {
            printf("File format is not RIFF. Exit.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        memccpy(buf, riff.type, '\0', 4);
        if (strcmp(buf, "WAVE")!=0) {
            printf("File format is not WAVE. Exit.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    };

    // Reading fmt.id and fmt.size
    if (fread(&fmt, sizeof(byte), 8, fp)!=8) {
        printf("Can't read fmt chunk or EOF is met. Exit.\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        memccpy(buf, fmt.id, '\0', 4);
        if (strcmp(buf, "fmt ")!=0) {
            printf("File have no fmt chunk. Exit.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Reading fmt Sample Format Info
    if (fread(&fmt.compression, sizeof(byte), fmt.size, fp) != fmt.size) {
        printf("Can't read Sample Format Info in fmt chunk or EOF is met. Exit.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Compression: %d\n", fmt.compression);
    printf("Channels: %d\n", fmt.chanels);
    printf("Sample Rate: %d\n", fmt.sample_rate);
    printf("Bit Rate: %d\n", fmt.bit_per_sample);

    // Reading data/some chunk
    if (fread(&data, sizeof(byte), 8, fp)!=8) {
        printf("Error of reading data chunk. Exit.\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        while (memccpy(buf, data.id, '\0', 4), strcmp(buf, "data")!=0) {
            fseek(fp, data.size, 1); // перемещаем указатель файла на конец чанка (его размер)
            fread(&data, sizeof(byte), 8, fp);
        }
    }

    // Reading PCM
    byte *dump = (byte*)malloc(data.size);
    if (dump == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation memory error");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fmt.compression == 1) {
        fmt.number_of_blocks = data.size / fmt.block_align;
        if ((fread(dump, fmt.block_align, fmt.number_of_blocks, fp))!=fmt.number_of_blocks) {  
            printf("Readin PCM data error.\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            strcat(filename, ".raw");
            if ((pcm_data = fopen(filename, "wb"))==NULL) {
                printf("Can't open the PCM file for write. Exit.\n");
                return 1;
            }

            if(fwrite(dump, fmt.block_align, fmt.number_of_blocks, pcm_data)!=fmt.number_of_blocks) {
                printf("Can't write PCM file. Exit.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("------------\nDone. PCM data writing in PCM file. Exit.\n");
        }

    } else {
        printf("Compression type is not PCM. Exit.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    free(dump);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(pcm_data);
    return 0;
}
```

wave.h

```c
typedef char                byte;  // 1 byte \ 8 bit 
typedef short int           word;  // 2 byte \ 16 bit
typedef unsigned int        dword; // 4 byte \ 32 bit

struct riff_chunk
{
    byte     id[4];             // 4b "RIFF" string  >|
    dword    size;              // 4b                 |-> 12 byte
    byte     type[4];           // 4b "WAVE" string  >|
};

struct fmt_chunk 
{
    byte     id[4];             // 4b "fmt" string
    dword    size;              // 4b _____
    word     compression;       // 2b
    word     chanels;           // 2b
    dword    sample_rate;       // 4b _____
    dword    byte_per_sec;      // 4b
    word     block_align;       // 2b
    word     bit_per_sample;    // 2b _____
    word     extra_format_size; // 2b _____
    byte*    extra_format_data; // 8b _____
    dword    number_of_blocks;  // 4b _____
};

struct data_chunk
{
    byte     id[4];             // 4 "data" string
    dword    size;              // 4
};

int dump(word*, dword*);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a great need to re-organise the structure of the code, other than to eliminate the unnecessary global variables (most can be moved to function scope).

There are a few portability problems that need to be addressed.  I'll start with the assumption about the width of integer types:

> ```
> typedef char                byte;  // 1 byte \ 8 bit 
> typedef short int           word;  // 2 byte \ 16 bit
> typedef unsigned int        dword; // 4 byte \ 32 bit
> ```

The comments are assumptions that will need to be verified for every platform you build this for.  There's a portable way to get what you want:

```
typedef uint8_t byte;
typedef uint16_t word;
typedef uint32_t dword;
```

Or just use the standard fixed-width types throughout - that's less confusing than inventing your own terminology.

Note that when using `printf()` and family, we need to use the correct specifiers.  This is wrong:

> ```
> printf("Compression: %d\n", fmt.compression);
> printf("Channels: %d\n", fmt.chanels);
> printf("Sample Rate: %d\n", fmt.sample_rate);
> printf("Bit Rate: %d\n", fmt.bit_per_sample);
> ```

With your original definitions, we should be using `%hu` for the first two of these and `%u` for the last two.  Using the standard fixed-width types, we get macros we can use for formatting:

```
printf("Compression: %" PRIu16 "\n", fmt.compression);
printf("Channels: %" PRIu16 "\n", fmt.chanels);
printf("Sample Rate: %" PRIu32 "\n", fmt.sample_rate);
printf("Bit Rate: %" PRIu32 "\n", fmt.bit_per_sample);
```

Here's an inefficiency:

```
    memccpy(buf, riff.id, '\0', 4);
    if (strcmp(buf, "RIFF")!=0) {
```

Firstly, `memccpy` isn't standard C (though it is defined by POSIX), so there's a small reduction in portability.  But there's no need to copy to `buf` here - just compare in place using `strncmp()`:

```
    if (strncmp("RIFF", riff.id, sizeof riff.id)) {
```

There's a lot of hard-coded sizes.  For example:

> ```
> if (fread(&riff.id, sizeof(byte), 12, fp)!= 12)  {
> ```

It's strange that we write `sizeof (byte)`, even though `byte` is just an alias for `char` (and so has size of 1 char), but then use `12` where we could more meaningfully write `sizeof riff`:

```
if (fread(&riff, 1, sizeof riff, fp) != sizeof riff)  {
```

(I also changed `&riff.id` to just `&riff` to make it clear that we're writing to the whole structure, not just the `id` member.)

When allocating, there's no need for (and possibly slight harm in) casting the returned `void` pointer to a more specific pointer size.  It's also idiomatic to use the inherent truthiness of a non-null pointer, rather that testing explicitly against `NULL`:

```
byte *dump = malloc(data.size);
if (!dump) {
```

I'm glad you didn't forget error checking here, and when opening files - that's an important part of programming in C, and you've got that right.  One small improvement: error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`:

```
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
```

BTW, don't forget when compiling to ensure that the structures are *packed*, without any padding between members.

An enhancement suggestion: allow the user to specify where to write the output (or just send it to standard out, and let them use their shell to redirect it).  We'll fail if the input file is in a read-only directory at present.

Comment: Thank You so much for detailed answer.

Comment: It is my first application on C. I did't know about `uint` types and `PRIu16` formatting. About `memccpy`: I'v tried to use `strcmp`, but `riff.id` and other members have only 4 bytes and no `\0` in last byte. Every comparison return `false`, but `buf` have 5 bytes where memccpy add the `\0` in last. Maybe I wrong. I don't know. What You think about it? Thank You for other.

Comment: Use `strncmp()` instead of `strcmp()` - this is how we compare sequences that might not be null terminated.  The extra argument is a maximum number of characters to compare if no NUL is reached.  BTW, welcome to the wonderful world of C programming.  It's frustrating at times, but rewarding eventually!

Comment: Sorry, I look at `strncmp()` but read `strcmp()` :) Thank You again!

Comment: I'v tried to use `strncmp()` but get a warning: `passing 'byte [4]' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign`. It is named **implicitly convert**, I think, right?

Comment: Well, we could explicitly cast, but it's probably better to change the type of `id` to `char[4]`, since we want to treat them as *characters* rather than unsigned small values.

Comment: Ok, what the right way to portability? Is `char` always equal 1 byte on all machines?

Comment: `char` is the smallest addressable unit of memory.  On any machine that has a `uint8_t`, then `char` must be 8 bits (it's not allowed to be less than that, and if it were greater, then there would be a smaller addressable type, which isn't allowed).  On systems where `char` is wider than 8 bits, `uint8_t` will be an error (rather than just silently wrong).

Comment: Just to add - systems with `char` between 9 and 15 are now quite rare; some specialised platforms (e.g. certain DSPs) have 16-bit `char`, but practically all general-purpose computers have 8-bit `char`.  The widths of `int`, `long`, etc. are more varied.